# Screen does not get widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen that loads some widgets according to a csv. But the screen just gets empty.

```
Column(
   children: getPlates(),
),
```

```
  List<Widget> getPlates() {
    List<Widget> listWidgets = [];
    listWidgets.add(Text('dew'));
    loadAsset('assets/Postres.csv').then((dynamic output) {
      List<String> list = output.split('\n');
      listWidgets.add(Text('holaaaa'));
      for (int i = 1; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
        List<String> sublist = list[i].split(';');
        listWidgets.add(CardPlate(
          name: sublist[0],
          ingredients: sublist[1],
          price: sublist[2],
        ));
      }
    });
    setState(() {

    });
    return listWidgets;
  }

  Future<String> loadAsset(String path) async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(path);
  }
```

I think it is because of the async method loadAsset that returns something when the screen is already bult. I tried loading it in initState but only works if I press hot reload

Answer (score 0):

As the assets are loaded asynchronously, they will not be populated in the synchronous `getPlates` function. You have a couple options here:

1. Use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). It is a very easy-to-use and powerful widget. This would be the approach I would recommend.
2. Make your `getPlates()` function `async` so you can use the `async` and `await` keyword, although I am not sure that is what you are looking for here as I am guessing you reference it from the build method.
3. Fix your current code; it has a bug. You `setState` after the then call. The correct approach is wrapping the `listWidgets.add` *inside* the `setState`, like so:

```
loadAsset('assets/Postres.csv').then((dynamic output) {
// Add the setState here like so
setState(() {
      List<String> list = output.split('\n');
      listWidgets.add(Text('holaaaa'));
      for (int i = 1; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
        List<String> sublist = list[i].split(';');
        listWidgets.add(CardPlate(
          name: sublist[0],
          ingredients: sublist[1],
          price: sublist[2],
        ));
      }
});
    });
```

Regardless of what method you pick to fix this--you probably shouldn't start loading the csv in the build method. Consider starting the load in your `initState` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `FutureBuilder` should solve your problem.

```dart
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: loadAsset('assets/Postres.csv'),
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      final output = snapshot.data;
      final list = output.split('\n');

      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          final sublist = list[index].split(';');
          return CardPlate(
            name: sublist[0],
            ingredients: sublist[1],
            price: sublist[2],
          );
        }
      );
    } else {
      return Text('awaiting the future');
    }
  },
),
```